# Help to understand the usage of 'hit' in "which could hit in early September"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> President Trump’s proposed tariffs on $200 billion worth of imported goods from China, which could **hit** in early September, has unnerved many American businesses and customers who think that Trump is causing unnecessary economic damage.

I am not sure what the exact meaning of **'hit'** in this context. I guess it means '**take effect**'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means that's when it will take effect. But, in this case, it also has a negative connotation.

From Merriam-Webster, here is what I think are the most equivalent senses of [**hit**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hit):

> transitive
>
> **3** : to affect especially detrimentally • farmers *hit* by drought • Many families were *hit* hard during the recession.
>
> intransitive
>
> **b** : to arrive with a forceful effect like that of a blow • the storm *hit*

So, it's going to arrive in September and those who are unnerved by it believe it will have a significant and negative impact.